# Another word for 'Unfinalize'

Tags: single-word-requests

I found that 'Unfinalize' is not a dictionary word. I want to use a word for the button that when clicked, shall restart/reopen a process or a page. Can you all help me with a good word that is concise, and user friendly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use "restart" or "reopen", or simply "edit"?

Comment: 'Reopen' may suit my cause. Thank you Nuclear Wang